how to merge children to an array in jsonata
How can I merge the objects from "123" and   "Trilby hat"
{
"123": {
"Price": 68.9,
"Qty": 2,
"ProductID": 858383
},
"Trilby hat": {
"Price": 21.67,
"Qty": 1,
"ProductID": 858236
}
}

to
{
"Items" : \[
{
"Price": 68.9,
"Qty": 2,
"ProductID": 858383
},  
{
"Price": 21.67,
"Qty": 1,
"ProductID": 858236
}
\]
}

here's the sample https://try.jsonata.org/Q84as3J_3

Select all the values using a wildcard:
{
   "Items": *
}

https://try.jsonata.org/NoyeBo8MS

Simply grab the entry values, and assign them to Items.
const actual = { Items: Object.values(raw) };

Demo
Note: The order of the resulting array is not guaranteed.


const raw = {
  "123": {
    "Price": 68.9,
    "Qty": 2,
    "ProductID": 858383
  },
  "Trilby hat": {
    "Price": 21.67,
    "Qty": 1,
    "ProductID": 858236
  }
};


const expected = {
  "Items": [{
    "Price": 68.9,
    "Qty": 2,
    "ProductID": 858383
  }, {
    "Price": 21.67,
    "Qty": 1,
    "ProductID": 858236
  }]
};

const actual = { Items: Object.values(raw) };

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected));



